# image in dompdf

Tags: php, dompdf

I used dompdf to generate pdf report. My report requires background images on every page. it works, but not that well. Dompdf consumes 2 or more minutes just to generate 2 pages with background image. Is there a way to optimize this?

Comment: Is your image optimized? Aren't you using a very big JPEG for your background?

Comment: actually, the image was a semi - transparent 100 X 100 png.

Comment: I set the image as the background of the main div that repeats vertically and horizontally

Comment: Two minutes seems extreme, what type of system are you running on? Do you have a sample document? PNG images have to go through a bit of processing before being inserted into a PDF. Transparent ones require additional processing on top of that. If you can install the PECL extension for either IMagick or GMagick you should see improved performance.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but I have tested many things with DOMPDF and I have read so many posts about slow processing of images and I have found out that using png or gif images in Dompdf makes the processing of the file very slow.

If you don't need to have transparency (alpha) on images, **use only jpg images** and you'll see that generation of PDF will be much faster.

Check this [github issue](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/730), which made me test the jpg solution.

Comment: I just confirmed this to be true, **rendering PDF using JPG instead of PNG is light years faster**. With PNGs I had to wait, and the more images - the more the waiting time. With JPGs it's fast regardless of how many images are being rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Insert some monitoring/profiling code and output results into the generated file to see what part is taking the longest. Shouldn't be a problem with images I bet it's a loop gone wild at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use external url

**DON'T**

```
url('storage/my-pic.jpg');
```

**DO LIKE THIS**

```
Use public_path('storage/my-pic.jpg');
```